# Linux based alternative for "PC Share Manager" for SAMSUNG TVs

Tags: linux, streaming

I have 2 samsung LED TV-s and I am trying to get my linux server at home to stream my media to the TVs.

I am looking for a solution for DLNA media streaming on a linux server to samsung LED TV, there is this official program from samsung called "PC Share Manager"  that is supposed to do the job, however it works only on windows.

I found these two blog posts:

- http://anotherdev.wordpress.com/2010/11/05/ubuntu-10-04-alternative-to-mediatomb-for-samsung-dlna-tvs-minidlna/
- http://anotherdev.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/samsung-le40c630-dlna-with-mediatomb-and-ubuntu/

I tried with mediatomb and minidlna and they do the work, but kind of buggy and can't fast forward and rewind, getting the pause working was not automatic either

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best DLNA server for Ubuntu?](http://superuser.com/questions/242986/what-is-the-best-dlna-server-for-ubuntu) also http://superuser.com/questions/250816/any-good-suggestions-for-media-server-software

Comment: What about running PC Share Manager on Linux through Wine. Recall, Wine Is Not an Emulator.

Comment: i tought about it , but since it is a server it will not be able to display the visual part which is needed in order to create the active directories, i guess i could make my own script that will be refreshing the database from the directory( in other words to simulate the active directory ) and it should work but writing that script would not be such easy task